# How many sequences of positive integers contain the positive integers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

If $$\Bbb{Z}^{+} = \{1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$$
Then there are a lot of sequences that contain $\Bbb{Z}^{+}$
$$\Bbb{Z}^{+} \subseteq \{i\}_{i=1}^\infty = \Bbb{Z}^{+}$$
$$\Bbb{Z}^{+} \subseteq \{ \left(\begin{array}{cc} 7 & i\textrm{ is odd}\\ i/2 & i\textrm{ is even} \end{array}\right) \}_{i=1}^\infty = \{7,1,7,2,7,3,7,\ldots\}$$
And many (more?) that clearly do not contain $\Bbb{Z}^{+}$.

My question is stated in the title.

I thought of this question while reading and thinking about [fractal sequences](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/patterns/weaving/webdocs/mo/H/FractalSequences.pdf). How many of [those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_sequence) are there? That is clearly another question.

Comment: So you're asking for $|\{f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N| f \text{ surjective }\}|$?

Comment: Um, yes. I think that is right.

Comment: As many as $|\mathbb{R}|$, just send $0.a_1a_2...$ to $a_1,1,a_2,2,\ldots$.

Comment: The question is not very well stated. 1. Sequences of what (positive number)? 2. You are confusing sets with sequences (a set cannot have duplicated elements) 3. "How many" does not have a clear meaning here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's at least one such sequence for each subset $A\subseteq \mathbb N$, namely
$$ f(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
5 & \text{if $n$ is odd and }\frac{n-1}2\in A \\
7 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

On the other hand, each function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ (surjective or not) can be encoded as a subset of $\mathbb N$, for example
$$ \{ 2^a3^b \mid f(a)=b \} $$

So, by the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem, the number of surjective functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is the same as the number of *all* functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, and the same as the number of subsets of $\mathbb N$, namely $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I think that the OP is thinkiing not in terms of cardinalities, but as some sort of proportion (measure)

Comment: No @leonbloy, this was exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: I'll accept the answer when it will let me. Does this mean (cardinality wise) I can write: $2^{\aleph_0} = \Bbb{N}^{\Bbb{N}}$?

Comment: @amcalde: Yes, though one would usually write either $|\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}|$ or $ \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you mean sequences in $\mathbb{Z}^+$ then the answer is pretty straightforward: as many as the real numbers.

This is easy to see: take any real number in its decimal representation and intertwine $\mathbb{Z}^+$ saying that if $a= a_1 \dots a_k \dots$ then

$x_{2n} = a_{n}$ and $x_{2n+1}=n$ is a sequence that contains $\mathbb{Z}^+$. This is injective so it's enough to say that what you're asking is $\geq |\mathbb{R}|$